# ES6 and ES7 features without babel transpiling in react-native?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-2017

I would love to use Javascript ES6 and ES7 syntax (especially async/await, my new best friends) without transpiling. Is that even an option? And should it be an option?

It all depends on the sub-question: what Javascript engine does react-native effectively use, on Android and iOS? Is it taken from the device itself? (in which case transpiling IS the only option...) Or is it provided by React Native?

Comment: ES7 (ES2016) only introduced two new features. `async/await` is part of ES2017.

Comment: Very true, it never made it into 2016. Gonna have to start using `+` after version names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can happily use `async`/`await` in React Native (you've been able to for awhile, in fact... since 0.10). As to using it without transpiling, that's a slightly stickier question. React Native requires only Node v6 and above, so obviously there's a fair bit of transpiling done via Webpack/Babel in order to ensure it still works with older versions of Node.

The deployed environment on the device is [JavaScriptCore](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore) (see [JavaScript Environment](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html) for more details). While you're debugging, you're using V8 via Chrome.